# How do you cleanly show intention when testing functions accepting blocks in RSpec?

Tags: ruby, rspec, bdd

I'm just getting into RSpec and playing around a bit with some easy examples and implementing a tree node structure with visitable nodes.

The first test I used to flush out the code with bdd was:

```
describe "Tree" do
  it "is visitable" do
    t = Tree.new
    visited = nil
    t.visit { |n| visited = n }
    visited.should == t
  end
end
```

This gets me the following implementation:

```
class Tree
  def visit(&block)
    block.call self
  end
end
```

I'm not too happy with the RSpec code at this point, as it doesn't really show the intention of what I'm trying to do very clearly, even though it works technically. When I move on to implement children, it gets even messier:

```
it "has visitable children" do
  c1, c2 = Tree.new, Tree.new
  t = Tree.new([c1, c2])
  visited = Set.new

  t.visit { |n| visited.add(n) }

  visited.should == Set.new([t, c1, c2])
end
```

This gets me the complete implementation:

```
class Tree
  attr_accessor :children
  def initialize(children=[])
    @children = children
  end

  def visit(&block)
    block.call self

    children.each { |c| c.visit &block }
  end
end
```

I'm happy enough with the resulting implementation (being an exploratory example and all), but is there an RSpec idiom that can make the spec more intentional and easily read?

**Edit: To clarify, I'm wondering if there are good ways of handling this with RSpec helpers/mocks etc.**

Comment: Do you mean `block.call self` in the first version of `Tree#visit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue that it is better if the tests also look right. The real question is why do TDD at all? To define you use cases (generally speaking) before you write the code and to define API so that it fits you use cases. At least this is my experience: by using TDD with RSpec or whatever I end up defining better interfaces to my code. This because the need to test as much of the functionality as possible requires to cut the API in a way that allows to access separate parts easily (and mock if needed).

So actually I would expect test cases to look like production code: because they would contain exact the same API as the production code. If it ends up messy, then it may only mean that you are yet not ready with your API?

Using mocks helps, too, because it expresses your expectations, like in

```
@target.should_receive(:print).exactly(1).times
```

**Answering the comment:** here are examples of mocking a block in your test case, explicitely stating expectations against the block:

```
describe "Tree" do

  it "is visitable" do
    t = Tree.new
    block = lambda { |n| n }
    block.should_receive(:call).with(t).exactly(1).times
    t.visit &block
  end

  it "has visitable children" do
    c1, c2 = Tree.new, Tree.new
    t = Tree.new([c1, c2])

    block = lambda { |n| n }
    block.should_receive(:call).with(kind_of(Tree)).exactly(3).times { |n|
      [t, c1, c2].include?(n)
    }

    t.visit &block
  end
end
```

Comment: So how would you change the example in the question to usefully use mocks?

Answer (score 1):

That looks more or less correct. Tests tend to look messier than application code, since they're really just runnable one-off examples of how your code should work. So I wouldn't obsess over beautifying your code too much.

That said you could clean up the examples a bit by putting object setup into a before(:each) block and/or separate your examples into contexts for single node trees and trees with children. Something like this:

```
    context "singleton trees" do
      before(:each) do
        @tree1 = Tree.new
        @tree2 = Tree.new
      end

      ...

      context "trees with children" do

        before(:each) do
          @tree_with_children = Tree.new([@tree1, @tree2)
        end     

       ...

      end
    end
```

Comment: Thanks, that's definitely useful. I tried adding some clarification in the question to show that I'm looking for new techniques to learn in RSpec. Having had bad experiences with runaway testcode, and having a possibly naive view that most code can be made to be easily understandable, I'm not yet ready to give up on making it clearer.